# Invalid Column Name on EF7 - RC2

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I get error "Invalid Column Name" on Entity Framework RC 2, below is my entities

```
public class Article : IEntityBase
    {       
       public Article()
        {
            TagMaps = new List<ArticleTagMap>();

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(100), MinLength(3)]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Metadata { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArticleTagMap> TagMaps { get; set; }

    }

public class Tag :IEntityBase 
    {
        public Tag()
        {
            TagMaps = new List<ArticleTagMap>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(100)]
        public string TagName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArticleTagMap> TagMaps { get; set; }


    }

public class ArticleTagMap : IEntityBase
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TagId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TagId")]
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
        public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

    }
```

and on DataContext I'm adding following code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTagMap>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Tag)
                .WithMany(b => b.TagMaps)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.TagId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleTagMap>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Article)
                .WithMany(b => b.TagMaps)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ArticleId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
 }
```

and from SQL profiler I catch the generated script

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [a0].[Id], [a0].[ArticleId], [a0].[ArticleId1], [a0].[TagId], [a0].[TagId1]
FROM [ArticleTagMaps] AS [a0]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(1) [a].[Id]
    FROM [Campaigns] AS [x]
    INNER JOIN [Articles] AS [x.Article] ON [x].[ArticleId] = [x.Article].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [Articles] AS [a] ON [x].[ArticleId] = [a].[Id]
    WHERE [x.Article].[Slug] = @__slug_0
    ORDER BY [a].[Id]
) AS [a1] ON [a0].[ArticleId1] = [a1].[Id]
ORDER BY [a1].[Id]',N'@__slug_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__slug_0=N'bantu-pekak-sanin'
```

There are ArticleId1 and TagId1 column name which is not available on table. I have struggling for several hour and still not find any solution. Please help :)

Comment: How did you fix this ? looks like a bug please respond.

Answer (score -1):

1) Try to remove `.HasForeignKey()` from `OnModelCreating` - you already have this info in `[ForeignKey(...)]` attributes (or, remove this attributes from `ArticleTagMap`) and re-create migration script

2) You do not need to catch SQLs in profiler. You can examine generated migration script (or `migrations/<DbContextName>DbModelSnapshot.cs` file with whole model) to ensure that EF "understands" your model correctly